# how android api call the native system library?

Tags: android, api, java-native-interface, system

in android.graphics.Typeface.java, call native functions(`nativeCreateFromAsset()`...),but I do
not find System.loadLibrary(). so,  By which means
does it load native library?

if I want to call a android system native lib in my app,
such as libandroid_runtime.so, how to do? I try to use
`System.loadLibrary("android_runtime")`but android_runtime
has not JNI_OnLoad().

thanks!

peng

Answer (score 0):

pls follow the link steps as given

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/
also see
http://psrdotcom.blogspot.in/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html

mysteps also see
Steps 1 create simple android project
Steps 2 create jni folder
Steps 3 create 2 file  Android.mk and ndkfoo.c in jni folder
Steps 4 make required code in both file
Steps 5 generate libs using command prompt 
Steps 6 project path untill jni folde> now ndk path untill ndk-build 
Steps 7 ex. D:\New_Wok_2\Firstndk\jni>c:\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build
Steps 8 if c file correct then its generate  libsabc.so file
Steps 9 Also in project refresh clean, here add new libs,obj folder  automatically